# How to read image from file .NetPortable 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, image, xamarin

I'm trying to simply read an image from file into a byte array. The problem is that I am using Xamarin and I want to decouple my Data Access code completely from Xamarin Forms. The problem is that my version of .Net (.NetPortable 4.5) does not contain System.IO.File so I don't know what to do now.

Can somebody point me in the right direction or recommend a lightweight package from Nuget? I want to achieve the follow without the use of Xamarin Forms and ideally load an image into a byte array with .NetPortable 4.5 or another light-weight mobile framework

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing; //Doesn't Exist in this .Net Framework!
using System.IO.File; //Doesn't Exist in this .Net Framework!
//using Xamarin.Forms; //I don't want to use Xamarin in this class

namespace EmployeeApp.DAT
{
 public class EmployeeImageDAT
 {

    private ImageSource _employeeImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("placeholder_image.png");

    public EmployeeImageDAT() {
    }

    public ImageSource EmployeeImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return _employeeImageSource;
        }
        set
        {
            _employeeImageSource = (value == null ? ImageSource.FromFile("placeholder_image.png") : value);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/

Comment: Thanks but this is using Xamarin Forms and what I'm trying to do is remove that dependency from Data Access. I need to be able to test this with MSTest and eventually have this code live in a separate solution

Comment: You could use the same approach with any DI engine, not necessarily the one built into XF.